# How can I stop or pause playframework Selenium tests on error?

Tags: testing, selenium, playframework

I'd like to stop or pause [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) test when running with playframework, because I can't see what is wrong!

Is there a way to preserve the window with my application on the step where it failed? It automatically closes that window!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a few things after you pin point exactly which step causes the error:

- Put a wait command in your selenium test to pause the test so you can see what is going on in the UI
- You could start the debugger and put a break point on some code that gets executed on the server after the failure happens (assuming the test continues running after the failure)
- You could use the selenium test runner panel to slow down the speed of the test so you can see the error (i.e. I'm referring to the speed slider that you see when you run the tests in the browser via the url http://localhost:9000/@tests)